# How to change the date of a specific line with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to put the dates in the to_datetime format, but the file has lines of form '26/04/2017' and '2017-04-27'. I am trying to use loc, to change only the lines that have dates of the form '26/05/2017'
but the change is not being made, even with the code compiling.

```
df_new = df.loc[df['Data'] == '26/04/2017' ]['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df2017.loc[df2017['Data'] == '26/04/2017' ]['Data'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

the code above is compiling, but only df_new is change

```
df.loc[df['Data'] == '26/04/2017' ]['Data']

Still showing the date in the format '26/04/2017'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have two assignments in code. I recommend you to create function:

```
     def change_date(date):
         if '/' in date:
             return pd.to_datetime(date, format='%d/%m/%Y')
         else:
             return pd.to_datetime(date)
```

And use apply method:
`df['Data'] = df['Data'].apply(change_data)`